# Is attaching authentication information to Kafka message secure practice?

Tags: authentication, security, apache-kafka

I have a long-running task which is to upload a CSV based on which a bulk of records insertion happens; so I delegate this to Kafka.
Those insertion operations need to be authenticated, meaning I make an authenticated API request.

My question is basically the title, is attaching authentication information to Kafka message secure practice?

And what are the options that I have?

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticator the Kafka broker and client.

Individual records cannot be "authenticated".

Kafka stores bytes, so any data in a record is not associated with specific clients. You could use private key pairs to "sign and encrypt" the CSV lines as *byte arrays*, for example, rather than include information as part of the record itself, in plaintext.

Comment: I didn't really get your answer. To insert a CSV record I need to make a call to some APIs, those APIs need to authenticate. Hopefully my question is more clear now

Comment: That's unrelated to Kafka, then. Kafka records are binary serialized. Anyone could decode your records, then see auth data in the record, so no, it is not a good idea to add to the records... **Unless** you authenticate Kafka itself, in addition to your API, or otherwise **encrypt** your binary data using key-pairs for example